# Trying to merge two Google Sheets FILTER function

Tags: filter, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a set of data, I would like to get only an extract of those data.
I'm able to do it with the use of this functions:

```
=filter(row($B$2:$B$10);search("3";$B$2:$B10))
```

[image: https://imgur.com/LlcZBYU.png]

Now I would like to search for everything that contains a "3" or a "1"

Here is what I tried:

```
=filter(row($B$2:$B$10);search("3";$B$2:$B10)+search("3";$B$2:$B10))
```

Get `#N/A` Nothing match

```
=filter(row($B$2:$B$10);search("3";$B$2:$B10);search("1";$B$2:$B10))
```

Get `#N/A` Nothing match

So I would like to get the result of

```
filter(row($B$2:$B$10);search("1";$B$2:$B10))
```

and the result of

```
filter(row($B$2:$B$10);search("3";$B$2:$B10))
```

at one go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
={FILTER(ROW(B2:B10), SEARCH("1", B2:B10));
  FILTER(ROW(B2:B10), SEARCH("3", B2:B10))}
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

You would need to put search inside isnumber:

```
=filter(row($B$2:$B$10),isnumber(search("3",$B$2:$B10))+isnumber(search("1",$B$2:$B10)))
```

The reason is that search gives an error if it doesn't find a match which is fine if you're just working with one value. If you try to combine the two values with '+' to get a logical 'OR', then only one of them can give a match so the whole expression always gives an error and you get no results.

Comment: @"Tom Sharpe" thanks it's working, it's not using the same "logic" but the result is there. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

or you can do:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({ROW(A:A), B:B}, 
 "select Col1 where Col2 =1 or Col2 =3", 0))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I'm not able to make it working.
I get QUERY: NO_COLUMN: Col2